# ObjectiveC, creating array of classes

Tags: objective-c, arrays, class, ios4, class-design

I have a class that contains values:

```
@interface Params : NSObject {
  [...]
  NSString *fc;
  NSString *sp;
  NSString *x;
  NSString *y;
  [...]
  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *fc;
  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *sp;
  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *x;
  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *y;
  [...]
@end
```

it's possible to create in objective-c an **array of classes**? like c# / java?

```
MyClass[] a = new MyClass[20] ???
a[0].fc = "asd" ?
```

or something equivalent?

thanks,
alberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the standard way to do this would be with an `NSArray`, you can do this with a C-style array as well:

```
int numObjects = 42;
Params ** params = malloc(sizeof(Param*) * numObjects);
for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; ++i) {
  params[i] = [[[Params alloc] init] autorelease];
}

free(params);
```

However, using an `NSArray` would be much simpler. :)

Comment: I would prefer a recursive autoreleased method myself

Answer (score 2):

You would use a standard `NSArray` to do this, in my example I have used views, but you can use pointers to any object.

```
    UIView * object = [[UIView alloc] init];
 UIView * object2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
 UIView * object3 = [[UIView alloc] init];

 NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:object,object2,object3,nil];

[object release];[object2 release];[object3 release];//edit

 UIView * test = [array objectAtIndex:0];
 test.tag = 1337;
```

Comment: do not forget to release your view objects - your code leaks memory

Comment: Also note that if you want to create something equivalent to an ArrayList, you want to use the mutable (aka modifiable) version of NSArray, it's subclass NSMutableArray